# Revolution Slider animate an existing layer with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, revolution-slider

I have an existing `Slider` with different Layers, including a `h1` tag.
So i want to animate this `h1` tag, triggered by a `Button`.
I´m using the Custom JS Editor, that comes with `Revolution Slider`.

So `durchstartenrev` is my button and `heiztechnikerev` is my `h1` tag

Whenever i click the button, its not even alerting.

Could anyone help me?

```js
$("#durchstartenrev").click(function(){
        $("#heiztechnikerev").animate({left: '250px'});
     alert("h");
    });
```

```css
#heiztechnikerev {
 position: absolute !important;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post `Code` as an `Image`. Stackoverflow has a pretty sick text editor for this.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your button has id 'durchstartenrev', but the code captures a click event on an element with ID 'der', as you posted:

```
 $("#der").click(function(){
    $("#heiztechnikerev").animate({left: '250px'});
    alert("h");
});
```

Should this not be:

```
 $("#durchstartenrev").click(function(){
    $("#heiztechnikerev").animate({left: '250px'});
    alert("h");
});
```

Comment: Just to confirm, the button has ID 'der', yes?

Comment: the button has ID 'durchstartenrev'

Comment: If it's not alerting, and you are not receving any errors, it leads me to believe that the event is not being binded to the button. Are you dynamically generating the elements by any chance? If so, you can use the 'on' method to attempt to get it to work. E.g. https://jsfiddle.net/JoelAndHowe/ksspxjh5/1/ . This functions by listening for any 'clicks' on the document, and then checking if the selector matches the criteria.

Comment: well i just put another alert to your function, but its still not alerting. I´m usung the custom JS for Revolution Slider. Maybe im doing it wrong there.
Here is my slider http://test.initiumit.de/heizung/
start animation is my testbutton

Comment: It's because, at this point, jQuery has not been defined. If you open up the debugger when viewing the page (F12), you'll see that you have an error stating that '$ is not defined'. If you move this into your '<!-- wp_footer() -->' block, this should now function

Comment: well i fixed it i think, but still http://test.initiumit.de/heizung/#slide5

Comment: The errors disappeared, so it looks like it. Hope I was of some help

Comment: yeah the error disappears, but it still doesnt work. In the admin panel, where is a short preview of the slider, it works

Comment: If the content is dynamically generated, it will not bind. Are you using the '.on('click' method, or the '.click(' method?